# C# How to write a xml file in code so that xna accepts to load it?

Tags: c#, xml, xna

After what I thought was successfully writing a xml document, xna refused to load it saying "XML is not in the XNA intermediate format. Missing XnaContent root element.".
A couple of answers to similar questions suggest changing the property, but in the end I want this file to be created at runtime and read at runtime. 
Aside from a dozen stackoverflow answers I also read most of the msdn entry about XmlDocument - without finding a magical "PutDocInIntermediateXNAFormat" method, what a surprise (I of course didn't look for a method with literally this name). 
I am certain I'm just missing the simplest of parts all Youtube videos about creating an xml file I watched just assumed to be known.
So before I am wasting any more hour, could anyone please grab my hand and guide me though this?

<s>Edit:
It seams xna isn't pleased with me trying to use an xml file that doesn't correspond to an underlying class. How can I get it to load regardless?</s>

Edit2:
I made a class and made xml files using this class. I have no problem saving it as an xml file nor loading it back into a class instanze. **However** I do have a problem using those xml files as assets for xna.
Here is the class:

```
namespace TheLemmingsGuideToMagrathea
{
 public class LevelSave
 {
     public int lemmingsToSpawn;
     public int lemmingsToSave;

     public int remainingStairs;
     public int remainingQuests;
     public int remainingGuidesv2;
     public int remainingThumps;
     public int remainingConciousnesses;

     public string[] map;
     public Point start;
     public Point finish;

     public int timeInSeconds;
 }
}
```

Here is the code that generates the xmlFiles from that class:

```
LevelSave save = new LevelSave();
save.map = level.Stringify();
save.start  = startLocation;
save.finish = finishLocation;
save.lemmingsToSpawn   = 50;
save.lemmingsToSave    = 25;
save.timeInSeconds     = 5 * 60;
save.remainingStairs   = 10;
save.remainingQuests   = 10;
save.remainingGuidesv2 = 10;
save.remainingThumps   = 10;
save.remainingConciousnesses = 10;

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LevelSave));

if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine("Content", "Levels")))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine("Content", "Levels"));
if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine("Content", "Levels", levelNameTextBox.Text)))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine("Content", "Levels", levelNameTextBox.Text));
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine("Content", "Levels", levelNameTextBox.Text, levelNameTextBox.Text + ".xml"));
serializer.Serialize(writer, save);
writer.Close();
```

And here is one xmlFile generated by that code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LevelSave xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <lemmingsToSpawn>50</lemmingsToSpawn>
  <lemmingsToSave>25</lemmingsToSave>
  <remainingStairs>10</remainingStairs>
  <remainingQuests>10</remainingQuests>
  <remainingGuidesv2>10</remainingGuidesv2>
  <remainingThumps>10</remainingThumps>
  <remainingConciousnesses>10</remainingConciousnesses>
  <map>
    <string> 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0</string>
    <string> 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0</string>
    <string> 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0</string>
    <string> 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0</string>
    <string> 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0</string>
    <string> 0,  0, 80,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0</string>
    <string> 0,  0, 80, 80,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0</string>
    <string> 0,  0,  0, 80, 80,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0</string>
    <string> 0,  0,  0,  0, 80, 80,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0</string>
    <string> 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 80, 80,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0</string>
    <string>11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11</string>
    <string>10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10</string>
    <string>10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10</string>
    <string>10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10</string>
    <string>10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10</string>
    <string>10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10</string>
    <string>10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10</string>
    <string>10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10</string>
    <string>10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10</string>
    <string>10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10</string>
  </map>
  <start>
    <X>1</X>
    <Y>9</Y>
  </start>
  <finish>
    <X>19</X>
    <Y>2</Y>
  </finish>
  <timeInSeconds>300</timeInSeconds>
</LevelSave>
```

I tried adding the
`<XnaContent>
   <Asset Type ="LevelSave">`
tags manually, which does indeed fixes it and finally lets me compile -- except it doesn't. It now gives the error `There was an error while deserializing intermediate XML. Cannot find type "LevelSave".` (I doesn't nag about not being able to be used as content anymore though.)
I'm mentally done for, please help me.

Comment: Can you post your XML and it's underlying class that will hold the data you're wanting to import? I used to use XML with XNA often and successfully. I found the most common problem that folks had was build order. Mainly not building the underlying class that would contain the data from the XML before the content processor tried to convert the file to xnb.  Is your data class in its own project that builds before your game project builds/runs? Not saying that's the problem but please post and we'll have a look.

Comment: That is interesting! I wasn't using an underlying class at all - all I wanted to do was save a smal amount of data like in the videos (I find it shocking that even thenewboston didn't have underlying classes in their tutorial!) Is it possible to do it without? Should I change the questions name to include that I want to load without a class?

Comment: This blog goes over the basics of having the content processor build an XML into an xnb file that can be consumed in XNA: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2009/03/25/automatic-xnb-serialization-in-xna-game-studio-3-1/ and this is the blog index where you would find that blog and many others that are indispensable when working with XNA: http://www.shawnhargreaves.com/blogindex.html

Comment: This blog is facinating, thanks! It suggests referencing the class out of another project, which I find a bit over the top. Isn't there any way to have the class in the same project?

Comment: The class that is referenced in your xml has to go through its build process before its needed. The content processor needs it when processing the xml to xnb so it must already be built. When you run your game, typically the content is processed first but if you create a project that the content project and the game project depend on, it will build first. Put the referenced class there. Its all because it has to be built before it can serve as a reference. If you put it in you game project or content project, it won't build in time.

Comment: Alright I will do it, thanks. I only wonder, why is it this way? This seams like an awful aproach, this is more of a hack than a salution

Answer (score 0):

From the "Missing XnaContent root element" message, I'd assume your XML document doesn't have an element called `XnaContent` at its root ...

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2008/08/12/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-intermediateserializer/

Does your generated XML look anything like this ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XnaContent>
  <Asset Type="TestClass">
    <GetSetProperty>Hello World</GetSetProperty>
    <PublicField>1</PublicField>
    <Nested>
      <Name>Shawn</Name>
      <IsEnglish>true</IsEnglish>
    </Nested>
  </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

Take note of the `<XnaContent>` root element ...

Comment: Well, actually, after stripping it of even its underwear, the doc had only the  <XnaContent></XnaContent> tags.

Comment: Although the headed looks nice, any idea how to implement it through code?

Comment: Depends how you are creating your XML in the first place. Alter your question to show how you are doing it.

Comment: I did. So, what did I do wrong? And to answer you're question again: no, it doesn't..